# controller not sending to view .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

controller not sending to view . I m trying to send request from controller to view , but its not redirecting . controller always redirect to index page. when i summit the form . its always redirecting same index page ,
controller not sending to view .controller not sending to view

My controller is sending to another view. but its not working .

```
    public IActionResult userLogin([FromBody] Users user)
        {




            string apiUrl = "https://localhost:44331/api/ProcessAPI";
            var input = new
            {
                email = user.email,
                password = user.password
            };
            string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(input);


         

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            //  client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl + "/userLogin", inputJson);
            //  List<Users> customers = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Users>>(json);

            user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users>(json);
        
              return  View();
 

        }

and  the view page is 

    
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model myproject.Models.Users
@{
    Layout = null;
}



<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Inventory Management System</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    @*   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./includes/style.css">*@
    @*<script type="text/javascript" rel="stylesheet" src="~/js/main.js"></script>*@


</head>


<body>


    <div class="overlay"><div class="loader"></div></div>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <br /><br />
    <div class="container">

        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            @*<?php echo $_GET["msg"]; ?>*@
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        @*<?php
            }
            ?>*@



        <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 20rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" style="width:60%;" src="./images/login.png" alt="Login Icon">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="form_login" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        @*<input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required />*@
                        <input asp-for="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="log_email" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="e_error" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="log_password" asp-for="password" id="log_password" placeholder="Password">
                        <small id="p_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lock">&nbsp;</i>Login</button>
                    <span><a href="register.php">Register</a></span>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"><a href="#">Forget Password ?</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {



            $("#form_login").on("submit", function () {




                var data = {
                    email: $("#log_email").val(),
                    password: $("#log_password").val(),
                    //  Phone: $("#phone").val()
                }

                //   data: $("#form_login").serialize(),
                // var data = $("#form_login").serialize();

                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Process/userLogin',
                    //  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Process", "Dashboard")';
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('Successfully received Data ');
                        console.log(result);
                        window.location.href = "Process/Dashboard";
                    //    window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/User/Home")';

                    //     window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Process", "Dashboard")';

                      //  window.location.href = DOMAIN + "/dashboard.php";
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed to receive the Data');
                        console.log('Failed ');
                    }
                })

            })




        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the name of your view and what is the name of your action? Try to pass the model and view name to the View() method of the controller. Try to return View(viewName, user) from your action.

Comment: my  view name is UserLogin

Comment: The View method has four overload. Try to pass model user to the View() method: return View(user); or both mode and user name: returnView("UserLogin", user);. You don't pass the model of your View as an argument to the View() method call.

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

From your code, since you want to use JQuery Ajax to submit the form data to the action method, in the form submit event, you should use the `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form submit action, then you can use JQuery Ajax to submit the form.

[image]

Second, does the Index page is the Process/Dashboard page? From your code, we can see in the Ajax success function, you will use the `window.location.href` to change the request URL, you can change the redirect page from here.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Hi @MEHDY MAHMOOD, How about directly using the button click event (change the submit button to a general button, and use its on click event to submit the form data to the controller action method), instead of using the form submit event. Besides, try to set break point in the controller method and the Ajax success function, whether they all triggered or not?